# Importing appcomba v7 library and got R cannot be resolved to a variable error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I've read a lot about importing v7 library to an android project but I am still stuck on to solve some of the error after that, I have a project and now I want to implement some material theme to it and having compatibility with previous android 5.0 versions. I have my project and I downloaded for the sdk the appcombat v7 library, these are the steps that I followed:

1) Copy the v7 android support library to my workspace (I've read some bug that causes eclipse to don't like to have the library in other directory)

2) File -> Import -> Existing android code into workspace

3) Search for my workspace directory, and click on v7 directory everything works fine.

4) Right click on my project -> Properties -> Android (my project has a minimun sdk of 14 and max of 21) and I have target set as 19 (4.2.2) then on library tab click on add and select android-support-v7-appcombat.

5) Project -> Clean.

This is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

This is my project.properties

```
# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

After doing this I get this error (my R file disappears)

[image: Android properties]

[image: R error]

On the sdk manager I've installed the Android SDK-Build tools rev 19 as I saw on differents post...but still getting the error

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: delete v4 jar file from v7 project and then clean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot one or two steps to **add libraries with resources** like appcompat.

You can find help here :
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

look at **Adding libraries with resources**

And if you followed all the steps, maybe the problem is elsewhere.

(Sorry for my English, I'm French)

Comment: nothing...I've repeated the steps on the link but keep the same error..R cannot be resolved to a variable..

Comment: Thank you Michaël, I did what you recommended me but adding the answer I just write

Answer (score 0):

Finally made it!

I've made the steps following what Michaël told me (I cannot add the link) but I've to manually go to right click on appcompat project -> Android and on project build target you have to select Android 5.0